# Linking to new SQL Server tables from an Access front-end

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, linked-tables

I'm using Access as a front-end for SQL Server.  I was able to link the tables no problem.  I was happily developing my user interface when I realized I needed a new table in my database.  I created that and populated it in SQL Server.  Now I want to link that table to my Access front-end.  I can find no obvious way in Access to link to newly created tables.  Is there way to do this and how would one go about doing it without having to start over with a new ODBC connection?  Thanks.
I'm using SQL-Server 2012 and Access 2012.

Answer (score 3):

On the "External Data" tab of the Access ribbon bar, in the "Import & Link" section, click "ODBC Database".

In the dialog that appears, select "Link to the data source by creating a linked table" and click "OK".

On the "Machine Data Source" tab of the subsequent dialog ("Select Data Source"), select the Data Source Name (DSN) that you created when you first set up the linked tables. Click "OK".

In the "Link Tables" dialog, select the new table(s) you recently created, then click "OK".